# ¿Cómo puedo capturar un dato de un datatable y enviarlo a php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, datatable

Tengo un formulario el cual capturo por php. Lo que quiero es tomar un dato de un datatable y enviarselo al metodo que procesa el formulario para luego guardarlo en la bd. Lo he hecho con AJAX y el dato del datatable llega al mismo metodo, pero cuando se envia de nuevo para procesar el formulario el dato se pierde.
Que puedo hacer.

Comment: Puedes proporcionar mas informacion? Por ejemplo ¿Que dato? Ademas adjunta codigo porque no sabemos como lo has realizado. Te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Necesito mas informacion de lo que preguntas. Por ejemplo podrias proporcionar el codigo para entenderlo mejor